# wierd crash when using new[] in qt

Tags: c++, qt

The following code will crash, I found it was related to “new []”

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QPushButton *buttons = new QPushButton[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
        buttons[i].setGeometry(0,0,30,40);
        buttons[i].setParent(this);
    }

}
```

after change new[] to normal array, it works fine

```
#mainwindow.h
QPushButton buttons[5];

#mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
        buttons[i].setGeometry(0,0,30,40);
        buttons[i].setParent(this);
    }

}
```

any ideas? thanks

Comment: The first example wouldn't compile..can you post the real code?

Comment: Looks like your heap is corrupt and the `new` is only making it surface.

Comment: I think the real reason is QT will destruct each button separately, which mean it will call 'delete' instead of 'delete []'

Comment: to compile the code ,just create a new GUI project using qt creator, then paste the code above.

Comment: *Where* (which line) does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Qt expert, but as far as I can tell, a `QObject` assumes ownership of all its child objects (it `delete`s them in the destructor).

If that is the case, you're not supposed to do any of those things you're doing - every `QPushButton` should be allocated *dynamically* and *individually* using `new`, and the fact that your second example doesn't crash is what's weird.

Comment: yes, every QPushButton has been destructed using delete, but they all should be deleted using "delete []"

Answer (score 1):

> any ideas?

I suspect the *QPushButton* is overloading the *operator new[]* and something in that operator is not quite right.

Because of this *operator new[]* you are seeing a difference between the static and allocated objects.

To see what I mean consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class QPushButton
{
public:
    QPushButton() {
        printf("Constructor\n");
    }

    void *operator new[](size_t size) {
        printf("New operator overloaded.\n");
        return new char[size];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argc;argv;
    printf("Stack defined objects\n");
    QPushButton button[5];

    printf("Allocated objects\n");
    QPushButton *p = new QPushButton[5];
    delete [] p;

    return 1;
}
```

and the resulting output:

```
C:\TEMP>test
Stack defined objects
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
Allocated objects
New operator overloaded.
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
Constructor
```

As you can see from the output above the new operator creates a difference between the local and allocated objects.